# Include minixsv in google app engine

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, xsd, xml-parsing, xml-validation

I want to make use of minixsv to validate an xml against an xsd. I read that google app engine supports this since it's 100% python. My question is, how do I add the minixsv to the GAE? if i do a:

```
from minixsv import pyxsval
```

I get an error...I'm obviously missing some setup things, any one know how I can set it up?

**Error:**

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named minixsv
```

Thanks!

http://www.familieleuthe.de/MiniXsv.html

GAE question:
https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/b457c9784df6a2f6?fwc=1&pli=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the library in your app's root directory. Put the `minixsv` directory (or `minixsv.py` if it doesn't have one) in the root directory of your app and try again.